# Kibana dashboard - add multi field control

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We need to create a new Kibana dashboard and add a control ( Option/dropdown selection https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/drilldowns.html#add-controls) in the dashboard.

So far I was able to just select one field in the Control and is working.

My problem is that I have to search by multiple fields: e.g all logs where "country" is "Spain" and the country values can be stored in a "country" field or in a "aaaa_country" field

Is there a way to have a dropdown in a Kibana dashboard that shows the value of both "country" and "aaaa_country" and once selected filter the logs by both fields ("country" == Spain or "aaaa_country" == Spain)?

Comment: do you find a solution for that ? i just encounter the same issue ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Also consider that the controls are an experimental feature. I would combine the two fields in a third `countries` field (as array or string) while ingesting the data and use such field in the controls.

Comment: Can be a solution, however if this new future will not be added can be pretty limitative for building Kibana dashboard without modifying the data

Comment: @Fabry try asking for a feature in github, but idk if they will care: for example, you can't use alias fields for this kind of use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/field-alias.html "Additionally, a field alias can only have one target. This means that it is not possible to use a field alias to query over multiple target fields in a single clause."